# Page Freezes with move.js animation loop

Tags: javascript, loops

The goal of this is to have this script run until a certain condition is met. In this case the condition would be that say a widget on the site has completed sending an Ajax request and received and processed a response.

Issue is that the page freezes up whenever the function load() is run.

```
var animateWrap = u(document.getElementsByClassName("process_transaction_wrapper"));
var i = 0;

function load(){
    animateWrap.append("<div class='loader'></div>");
    // Create Loading Object
    move(".loader")
        .set("width", "25px")
        .set("height", "25px")
        .y(75)
        .set("background-color", "#ccc")
        .end();
    while(i < 1) {
        move(".loader")
            .y(0)
            .rotate("180")
            .duration("2s")
            .end(function(){
                move(".loader")
                    .y(75)
                    .rotate("360")
                    .duration("2s")
                    .end();
            });
    }
}
function endLoad(){
    i++;
}
```

Comment: yeah, because `while(i < 1)` is never resolved isnt it? So the loop will keep running in CPU time. The browser's solution in order to prevent your system from going tits up is to freeze the page.

Comment: @AbanaClara That is until endLoad() is called. Is there a method to do this in order to prevent the freeze?

Comment: Yeah, but `endLoad()` isn't called; so therefore, the loop runs endlessly. Call endLoad() inside `.end()` on your chain of methods. However, I do not know this library so I am not sure.

Comment: @AbanaClara it is just an animation library. What I am trying to do is wait till `i` is changed from another function being receiving a response back.

Comment: You are executing `move()` very repetitively at an extreme pace inside that loop. That is going to cause a freeze. You want to run a recursive timeout or a simple interval, preferably after your `.duration(2s)` ends.

Answer (score 0):

You are executing `move()` very repetitively at an extreme pace inside that loop. That is going to cause a freeze. You want to run a recursive timeout or a simple interval, preferably after your `.duration(2s)` ends.

```
var animateWrap = u(document.getElementsByClassName("process_transaction_wrapper"));

var timer = null; //initialize a timer variable to hold timeout

function load() {
    animateWrap.append("<div class='loader'></div>");
    // Create Loading Object
    move(".loader")
        .set("width", "25px")
        .set("height", "25px")
        .y(75)
        .set("background-color", "#ccc")
        .end();

    callMovement(); //start movement OR call this in the end() function of the initial loading object
    keepMoving();   //start continuous movement
}

function keepMoving() {
    //assign a timeout to the timer
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        callMovement();
        keepMoving(); //call same function again after 2000ms. You could probably call this inside .end() on this animation library of yours to preserve accuracy.
    }, 2000);
}

function callMovement() {
    move(".loader")
        .y(0)
        .rotate("180")
        .duration("2s")
        .end(function () {
            move(".loader")
                .y(75)
                .rotate("360")
                .duration("2s")
                .end();
        });
}

function endLoad() {
    clearTimeout(timer); //call this to stop recursion
}
```

Wait are you creating a loading spinner? You can easily make this on css and toggle movement and displays by simple class manipulation. It is miles easier than manually doing such a small task in JS